# How to create a copy with graphical or histographic progress

Tags: c#, graphics, download, copy

friends.
I have doubts on how to create an application where I can graphically show the download, I already programmed the download part but I lack the graphic form. To give you an idea, I want to make a graphic model like Windows 10 does when you make a copy of a file or several files to a folder. I hope they understand me. The design of graphics and even more when it is required to calculate does not turn out well to me.
Thank you.

Comment: What are you using for UI? WindowsForm? browser?

Comment: so you want a progressbar? Can you show your code?

Comment: A W10 file copy progress window looks like a chart. You need to show what you want in an image and also tell us what are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
Always __TAG__ your question correctly! - As it stands, the question is way too broad. The least we would also need to see is some code from and/or  the interface of your 'download part'.

Comment: I use WindowForm (WinForm)...